# TextWatcher not immediately triggered

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have a TextWatcher on an EditText. In afterTextChanged, I have code to do a call to a web service, and get the results. But it is called immediately after the user enters the first character. I want it to trigger only when the user has not been writing on the EditText for a while, so the user can search for two or more characters. How could I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: In the method:  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)  you can make a check on the length of the String and call the web service accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback will be called on each added/removed character.

Start the delay by yourself and cancel it to launch it again whenever you have a change in the EditText.

Comment: Of course, a delay...TimerTask and everything. Can't believe I didn't thought about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below things on **afterTextChanged()** to call webservice only after two or more characters are entered by user

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String enteredValue  = s.toString();
        if(enteredValue != null && enteredValue.trim().length >= 2)
        {
           // Call Webservice
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought doing that...but sometimes the user would want to enter only one character

Comment: you can change value in IF condition. I have set required input length to 2.